# How to read variables in a file into shellscript?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My input file `xyz` is:

```
x=1
y=2
z=3
```

My shell script is like:

```
 if[ "$x" -eq 1]
  then
     .....
 fi 
 echo "$z"
```

Then how to read variables from the input file `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the values of variables defined in `input.txt`

```
x=1
y=2
z=3
```

In your file, where you want to use them, you can do the following:

```
. input.txt
echo $x
echo $y
```

Answer (score 0):

You script should look like this:

```
. ./xyz
if [ "$x" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "$x"
fi
```

Notice that between `[` and `]` must be spaces. With the `.` you can execute the shell code within a given file (that hasn't to be executable).